# ESP32 BLE Mesh only connected node can receive on/off commands

Tags: esp32, espressif-idf

I am currently trying to implement esp32 BLE Mesh but cannot seem to figure out why only the currently connected node will respond to on/off commands

Currently i am following the example in https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/esp_ble_mesh/ble_mesh_node/onoff_server and already flashed the code to 3 esp32 boards

using the nRF android app i have done the following:

1. provision all nodes
2. assign app key to all on/off models
3. turn led on/off

now the main problem i am facing is that the BLE mesh feature does not seem to be working as expected, only the currently connected node responds to on/off messages, and trying to turn on an led on another node does nothing. Anyone have an idea on what i have missed, and why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my specific board ESP32-WROOM-32U did not have internal antenna, if the boards are <1cm apart then it finally works, after purchasing antenna it is now working fine